# glDrawElements doesn't draw anything

Tags: java, opengl, vbo

I am pretty new to VBOs, VAOs and Indices. I was able to render a single cube and now I am trying to render a chunk of cubes. My goal is to slowly make a voxel engine. I have a problem with my chunk class. It doesn't display anything for some reason. Can anyone take a quick look and maybe figure out whats wrong and point it out to me? Cheers

```
class Chunk {

private IntBuffer vaoID;
private IntBuffer vboID;
private IntBuffer indexID;


public void createChunkVBO() {

    FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 3 * 8);
    FloatBuffer colors = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 4 * 8);
    FloatBuffer indices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 4 * 6);

    vaoID = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1); // Create a buffer for the Vertex Array Object
    vboID = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1); // Create a buffer for the Vertex Buffer Object
    indexID = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1); // Create a buffer for the Vertex Indices


    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
                System.out.println(x + ", " + y + ", " + z);
                vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(y);
                vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                vertices.put(x);
                vertices.put(y);
                vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                vertices.put(x);
                vertices.put(y);
                vertices.put(z);

                vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(y);
                vertices.put(z);

                vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                vertices.put(x);
                vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                vertices.put(x);
                vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(z);

                vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                vertices.put(z);


                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);

                colors.put(1f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(0f);
                colors.put(1f);


                indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(2 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(3 + x * y * z);


                indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(5 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(2 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(3 + x * y * z);


                indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(3 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(7 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(5 + x * y * z);


                indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(3 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(7 + x * y * z);


                indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(6 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(7 + x * y * z);


                indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(5 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(6 + x * y * z);
                indices.put(7 + x * y * z);

            }
        }
    }


    glGenVertexArrays(vaoID); // Create an id for the VAO
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID.get(0)); // Bind the VAO so it remembers all the Attributes (none right now)

    glGenBuffers(vboID); // Create an id for the VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID.get(0)); // Bind the VBO so we can put data into it

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 7 * Float.SIZE, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // We make an empty buffer with a specific size in bytes
                                                                        // 8 * 7 * sizeof(float)
                                                                        // 8 = number of vertices, 7 = xyzrgba

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices); // Put the vertices at the beginning of the buffer
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 3 * Float.SIZE, colors); // Put the colors after the vertices

    glGenBuffers(indexID); // Create an id for the Index Buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID.get(0)); // Bind the Index Buffer so we can put data into it
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Store the indices inside the currently bound Index Buffer

}

public void drawChunk() {

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // Enable the Vertex Array
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); // Enable the Color Array

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 3 * Float.SIZE); // Position of the colors in the currently bound buffer

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24 * 16 * 256 * 16, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // Draws the elements from the Index Buffer

}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I can offer an immediate solution, as the question is not very specific, but I can offer some general advice that may help you solve your issue:

1. Your chunk class should have only one vaoID (the entire chunk should be rendered with one draw call). It can have multiple vboID's that are associated with that one vaoID. The point is, there is no need to use IntBuffers to store them, and it will typically keep things more organized if you explicitly name each of the vboID's.
2. After you create your FloatBuffer objects with BufferUtils and load data into them, you must call .flip() on all of them so that OpenGL knows they are ready to be used. (This is most likely the MAIN, possibly only, issue)
3. As general courtesy to the rest of your program, you should disable any attributes that you enable during your draw method and unbind any VAOS that are bound. (I believe when you bind a buffer object while a VAO is bound, that buffer is only bound when the VAO is ALSO bound. I can't find the documentation to back this up, so to be safe I would also unbind the buffer objects after you're done with them)
4. Below is what I believe should give you a working implementation of your Chunk class:

   ```
   class Chunk {

   private int vaoID;
   private int vboID;
   private int indexID;


   public void createChunkVBO() {

       FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 3 * 8);
       FloatBuffer colors = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 4 * 8);
       FloatBuffer indices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 256 * 16 * 24);

       // I am assuming that all of this is generated properly
       for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
           for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
               for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
                   System.out.println(x + ", " + y + ", " + z);
                   vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(y);
                   vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                   vertices.put(x);
                   vertices.put(y);
                   vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                   vertices.put(x);
                   vertices.put(y);
                   vertices.put(z);

                   vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(y);
                   vertices.put(z);

                   vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                   vertices.put(x);
                   vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(z + World.BLOCK_SIZE);

                   vertices.put(x);
                   vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(z);

                   vertices.put(x + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(y + World.BLOCK_SIZE);
                   vertices.put(z);


                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);

                   colors.put(1f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(0f);
                   colors.put(1f);


                   indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(2 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(3 + x * y * z);


                   indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(5 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(2 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(3 + x * y * z);


                   indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(3 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(7 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(5 + x * y * z);


                   indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(3 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(7 + x * y * z);


                   indices.put(0 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(1 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(6 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(7 + x * y * z);


                   indices.put(4 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(5 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(6 + x * y * z);
                   indices.put(7 + x * y * z);

               }
           }
       }

       vertices.flip();
       colors.flip();
       indices.flip();


       glGenVertexArrays(vaoID); // Create an id for the VAO
       glBindVertexArray(vaoID); // Bind the VAO so it remembers all the Attributes (none right now)

       glGenBuffers(vboID); // Create an id for the VBO
       glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID); // Bind the VBO so we can put data into it

       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 7 * Float.SIZE, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // We make an empty buffer with a specific size in bytes
                                                                       // 8 * 7 * sizeof(float)
                                                                       // 8 = number of vertices, 7 = xyzrgba
       // I have not used subdata like this before so I will assume this is correct.
       glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices); // Put the vertices at the beginning of the buffer
       glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 3 * Float.SIZE, colors); // Put the colors after the vertices


       glGenBuffers(indexID); // Create an id for the Index Buffer
       glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID); // Bind the Index Buffer so we can put data into it
       glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Store the indices inside the currently bound Index Buffer

   }

   public void drawChunk() {

       glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // Enable the Vertex Array
       glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); // Enable the Color Array

       glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
       glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 16 * 256 * 16 * 8 * 3 * Float.SIZE); // Position of the colors in the currently bound buffer

       glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 8 * 16 * 256 * 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // Draws the elements from the Index Buffer
   }
   }
   ```

Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions about anything that I have said.

**Disclaimer:** I am not an expert with OpenGL or LWJGL. Please take my answer with a grain of salt as these answers come almost purely from my educational/personal experience.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant answer! I have indeed forgotten to flip the FloatBuffers. Flipping them partially fixes the problem. When I use glDrawArrays I get the quads to render properly. However, there are only 2 quads per cube, since I want to use indices. glDrawElements doesn't seem to work for some reason. My guess is that I messed up with adding the indices for each cube. Thank you for all the great tips! Is there any chance you could possibly take a look at how I store the indices, since you are way more experienced with OpenGL in general than me. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I've read your comment and will test shortly. I'm on my desktop at home which needs Eclipse and JDK installed before I can even do simple testing lol...I will get back to you and edit my answer when I have looked at it.

Comment: I have to apologize that I do not have time to answer this in a timely manner between work and school. I have corrected the index buffer sizes both on the line where indices is initialized and on the line with glDrawElements. This could fix your problem. If not, I would suggest starting with a small example first then working your way up to a chunk. e.g., Start with a cube, then a line of cubes, then a grid of cubes, then a chunk of cubes.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was laying in hospital. Thank you very much for all the time you have put into answering this question. This unfortunetly didn't resolve the issue. I am starting with a small example as you instructed. Once again, thanks!